# How to measure the similarity among vectors

Tags: vector-spaces

## Question

Suppose there are three vectors $x$, $y$, and the target $t$.

- The angle between $t$ and $x$ is smaller than that of $t$ and $y$, but
- The distance between $t$ and $y$ is smaller that that of $t$ and $x$

Which vector $x$ or $y$ should I say "more similar" to $t$ and what formula to use to quantify it?

[image]

## Background

[word2vec](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.4546) or more generally [Thought Vectors](https://wiki.pathmind.com/thought-vectors) encodes the similarity of words or concepts into fixed length vectors. Suppose this vector space is $W$ and each vector has $D$ dimensions (features).

Then $queen \approx (king-man) + woman$ can be achieved using the vectors.

[Implementing Word2Vec in Tensorflow](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/implementing-word2vec-in-tensorflow-44f93cf2665f)

[image]

However, not sure how this "Similarity" should be defined and measured in the vector space. What would it mean "angle is smaller but distance is larger" or "angle is larger but distance is smaller".

I can think of below but not sure which ones to use.

1. Distance measured as $|t - x|$
2. Angle measured as $\frac {t}{|t|} \cdot \frac {x}{|x|} $
3. Dot product $t \cdot x$

Articles discusses cosine, Word mover’s distance, Euclidean distance, etc but it looks there are no solid discussion over the meaning of each method and why use them.

- [Calculating Document Similarities using BERT, word2vec, and other models](https://towardsdatascience.com/calculating-document-similarities-using-bert-and-other-models-b2c1a29c9630)
- [What is the best way to measure text similarities based on word2vec word embeddings?](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_best_way_to_measure_text_similarities_based_on_word2vec_word_embeddings)

Hence would like some guidances on how to understand "Similar" in a vector space and what formulas to use to quantify it.

Comment: Let $t=(5,0)$, $x=(4,0)$, and let $y$ be the vector of length $5$ at the angle $\theta$. If $\theta$ is small, then $y$ is more similar to $t$ than $x$ is. If $\theta$ is large, then $x$ is more similar to $t$ than $y$ is. How large does $\theta$ have to be, for $x$ to be the more similar vector? I don't think that's a question of mathematics; I think it's a question of your personal opinion. Once you can answer that question for yourself, you can start evaluating formulas on how well they agree with your own judgements.